# broadcasting/auth cors error using laravel et angular

Tags: angular, laravel, websocket

i want to do chat `pusher` `websocket` use `laravel` and `angular` ,i have configure `laravel` and it works fine ,because i tried `api` in `postman` and it works fine when i add `socket_id` and `channel name` ,message send successfully and request api

```
http://127.0.0.1/chatestb/public/broadcasting/auth return {
     "auth": "9d80a4aa39484cd65055:dbf25cefb383d8ec42c95e25d22d2dec3686a5de7fce4fc126a6c185c122ea10"
},
```

see picture:
[image: postman]

now i want to `listen` by `angular` but it gives me error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/chatestb/public/broadcasting/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
src\assets\js\pusher.min.js:8 POST http://localhost/chatestb/public/broadcasting/auth net::ERR_FAILED
```

knowing that I have already configured `CORS` and it works well

**chat.component.ts**

```
  echo!: Echo;
  inputMessage!: string;
  username = 'Najib';
  allMessages: Messages[] = [];

  constructor(private chatService:ChatService,private tokenService:TokenService) {
    this.websocket();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGroupChat();
  }

  websocket() {
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken();
     this.echo = new Echo({
      authEndpoint: `http://localhost/chatestb/public/broadcasting/auth`,
      auth: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      },
      broadcaster: 'pusher',
      key: '9d80a4aa39484cd65055',
      cluster: 'eu',
      wsHost: 'localhost',
      wsPort: 6001, 
      forceTLS: false,
      disableStats: true,
    });
  }

  getGroupChat() {
    this.echo.private('chat')
      .listen('ChatEvent', (res:any) => {
        const message: Messages = {
          message: res.message,
          me: false,
          from: res.from
        };
        this.allMessages.push(message);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

nginx and server already allow CORS? Check if your http response header contains Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
If it's the same site, pay attention to the path of your API. For example, you can consider using relative paths